# Azure Function binding attributes - Database name setting - VS2017 preview tooling

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the new tooling for Azure Functions projects in VS2017 Preview and have ported some functions from the Azure portal to the new projects.

I'm binding to an Azure Document DB - it's working fine, but when I use the `DocumentDB` attribute I have to supply the database name as the first parameter.

In my case it's the DEV database for now .. but of course there will be other environments - is there a way I can pick up the database name via an application setting for the function app?

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggeredFunction")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log,
                       [DocumentDB("my-db-DEV", "MyCollection")]  IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocuments)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use app settings for these values by using the `%%` auto resolve syntax for app settings. For example, if you've added app settings named `DB_DEV` and `COLLECTION_DEV` (either in the portal, or when running on your local box), you can reference those in your attribute like so:

```
[DocumentDB("%DB_DEV%", "%COLLECTION_DEV%")]
```

Those app settings will then be resolved at runtime. The "Resolving App Settings" section in our documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) explains this in more detail.

Comment: Do make sure you have the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB` referenced in your project. Otherwise the this attribute will not be found. Just stumbled across this a minute ago

Answer (score 1):

I'd overlooked the fact that the Azure Cosmos DB connection string can be specified via the `local.settings.json` file for my Azure function project.

It's in here that I'd provide the appropriate connection string for the environment I'm targetting. Then I can use consistently named Databases and Collections within those accounts, meaning the function signature is correct in all environments.

`[DocumentDB("my-db", "MyCollection")] IEnumerable<dynamic> inputDocuments`

And provide the connection string in `local.settings.json` under the default key, `AzureWebJobsDocumentDBConnectionString`

Comment: Why use the `local.settings.json` and not the App Settings in the Application Settings (inside the AppService)? This way your `local.settings.json` will not contain any sensitive information and your connection string will be accessible as an environmental variable

Comment: Thanks Chris - I have set those values in the Application Settings via the portal to be used when I deploy the function.  When running locally via VS2017 preview, is there a better way to access those settings than using `local.settings.json`?